# Polymer - icon with paper-badge

Tags: css, icons, polymer, polymer-1.0

I tried use the paper-badge.I wrote this code:

```
<iron-icon id="star" icon="icons:star-border" style="fill:blue;height: 38px;
        width: 58px;"></iron-icon>
<paper-badge label="6" for="star"></paper-badge>
```

My problem is that the 6 is not close to the star.

[image]

I want to make it more like

[image]

I dont know if their is attribute in polymer for doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify `paper-badge`'s custom css properties to achieve this. Note that I changed the `width` of the `iron-icon` to `38px`.

```
<style>
    paper-badge {
        --paper-badge-margin-left: -8px;
        --paper-badge-margin-bottom: -12px;
    }
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
    <iron-icon id="star" icon="icons:star-border" style="fill:blue;height:38px;width:38px;"></iron-icon>
    <paper-badge label="6" for="star"></paper-badge>
</div>
```

Check it out [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tEhHHxsELak8LdOhYLT2?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

**paper-badge** has two simple properties

```
<paper-badge for="btn" label="♥︎"></paper-badge>
```

Default width and height:

--paper-badge-width The width of the badge circle   22px

--paper-badge-height    The height of the badge circle  22px

Custom CSS Styling can be changed in

```
<style>
    paper-badge {
        --paper-badge-margin-left: 22px;
        --paper-badge-margin-bottom: 22px;

    }
</style>
```

Regarding **iron-icon**

Default width and height's are

--iron-icon-width   Width of the icon   24px

--iron-icon-height  Height of the icon  24px

and you can customize in your own way by changing in styles

if you could use same default height and width values for booth paper-badge and iron-icn , you can get the view you want.

Please go through the polymer elements docs for more reference

[iron-core](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-icon) , [paper-badge](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-badge)